# plugin is not running except from console: cannot execute 'alert' of undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have installed a diaglog plugin for cordova. When I run it, I get an error saying "cannot call method 'alert' of undefined".

When I execute the same function from the console, it runs perfectly.

This is my index.html file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/org.apache.cordova.dialogs/www/notification.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        navigator.notification.alert( <--------------------- here!!
        'You are the winner!',  // message
        function(){

        },         // callback
        'Game Over',            // title
        'Done'                  // buttonName
        );

      });
    </script>
    <LINK rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"> 
  </head>
  <body >
    <div> hello world</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you definining navigator/notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to wait for the [DeviceReady Event](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready).

The plugin is not initialized in

> $(document).ready();

The document gets loaded -> document ready -> cordova starts to initialize -> deviceready

Comment: thanks very much. as soon as I read the first line, I immediately understood. 
thanks again.